# Browser back button issue with partial view in ASP.NET MVC 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working an ASP.NET MVC3.0 application.

After login the user is redirected to the dashboard default page. 
The dashboard contains several links. When you click on a link the partial view is rendered. Internal content get changed. The browser URL/page doesn't change.

So when user goes from Link 1-->Link 2-->Link 3 and when they pressed back button on browser then ideally Link 2 content should get displayed. But in my case it redirects to dashboard default page.

The same problem is posted here but without solution: [Browser back button issue with ASP.NET MVC3 web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903118/browser-back-button-issue-with-asp-net-mvc3-web-application).

Please reply if any one have solution on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code.(how you write links on page, and methods in controller)
Probably you are need write routing for youself. Looks Sammy.JS for example

Comment: Seems this is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112989/support-browser-back-button-with-ajax-without-relying-on-a-hash-change

Comment: Does Link 2 always render a partial view or only a partial view on an ajax request?